# Select 2 dropdown not giving the id of the selected item how do i access for controller bind

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

For some reason my select to cannot get access to the id value I have setup a few counties as such I am using the https://select2.org/ dropdown to be able to show images of countries

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2').select2()
    var isoCountries = [
        { id: 1, flag: 'af', text: 'Afghanistan' },
        { id: 2, flag: 'ax', text: 'Aland Islands' },
        { id: 3, flag: 'al', text: 'Albania' },
        { id: 4, flag: 'dz', text: 'Algeria' },
        { id: 5, flag: 'as', text: 'American Samoa' },
        { id: 6, flag: 'ad', text: 'Andorra' },
        { id: 7, flag: 'ao', text: 'Angola' },      
   ]; 

function formatCountry(country) {
    if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
    var $country = $(
        '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-' + country.id.toLowerCase() + ' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
        '<span class="flag-text">' + country.text + "</span>"
    );
    return $country;
};

//Assuming you have a select element with name country
// e.g. <select name="name"></select>

$("[name='Flag']").select2({
    placeholder: "Please Select a country",
    templateResult: formatCountry,
    data: isoCountries
});
<script>
```

When I look at the generated content for the drop down select for which is produced as such.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryOfBirth)
    <span asp-validation-for="CountryOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
    <select asp-for="CountryOfBirth" name="CountryOfBirth" id="CountryOfBirth" class="form-control select2" style="height:35px" name="Flag">
        <option>Please select Country Of Birth</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="CountryOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

And generated as such no where in the html is the id for the selected item so how would the controller be able to bind it

```
<span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-CountryOfBirth-container">

<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-CountryOfBirth-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</span>

<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<select asp-for="CountryOfBirth" name="CountryOfBirth" id="CountryOfBirth" class="form-control select2" style="height:35px" name="Flag">`

From the codes above, you set name attributes for the `select` tag three times.

- asp-for="CountryOfBirth"
- name="CountryOfBirth"
- name="Flag"

Just keep `asp-for` and delete others. `asp-for` attribute extracts the name of the specified model property into the rendered HTML.

> Codes of view

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryOfBirth)
        <span asp-validation-for="CountryOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
        <select asp-for="CountryOfBirth" class="form-control select2" style="height:35px">
            <option>Please select Country Of Birth</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="CountryOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

> Codes of JS

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        //$('.select2').select2();
        var isoCountries = [
            { id: 1, flag: 'af', text: 'Afghanistan' },
            { id: 2, flag: 'ax', text: 'Aland Islands' },
            { id: 3, flag: 'al', text: 'Albania' },
            { id: 4, flag: 'dz', text: 'Algeria' },
            { id: 5, flag: 'as', text: 'American Samoa' },
            { id: 6, flag: 'ad', text: 'Andorra' },
            { id: 7, flag: 'ao', text: 'Angola' },
        ];

        function formatCountry(country) {
            if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
            var $country = $(
                '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-' + country.flag + ' flag-icon-squared"></span>' +
                '<span class="flag-text">' + country.text + "</span>"
            );
            return $country;
        };

        //Assuming you have a select element with name country
        // e.g. <select name="name"></select>
        $("[id='CountryOfBirth']").select2({
            placeholder: "Please Select a country",
            templateResult: formatCountry,
            data: isoCountries
        });

        $('#CountryOfBirth').val(@Model.CountryOfBirth); //init option
        $('#CountryOfBirth').trigger('change');

    });
</script>
```

> Test of result

[image]

Comment: Is their any way to also get the flag sent to the controller so that i can save the flag lowercase vairint to the db column

Comment: Hi, @rogue39nin, sorry for the late reply but  it's inconvenient to describe here. If you're still looking forward to new question, please post in new thread and detail **the flag lowercase vairint**.